# How to cite an image from Wikipedia/other research paper in ACM research paper

Tags: graphics, acm

I want to include an image from Wikipedia (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Colored_neural_network.svg) and an image from other research paper in my paper (ACM SIG template).

How should I cite these images?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more a question about academic purpose than TeX related and so should be ask on academia.SE